# Hide status bar only on iPhone 5, 5s, SE

Tags: iphone, swift

Is it possible to hide status bar of my app only for iPhones with small screens? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it probably is.

Comment: Are you looking for how to accomplish this? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone 5, 5S and SE have a screen width of 320. In your `AppDelegate` you could do the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.width == 320 {
        application.isStatusBarHidden = true
    }
    return true
}
```

And go to your info.plist and add a new value:
`View controller-based status bar appearance` set the value to `NO`. The status bar will now be hidden for iPhone 5, 5S and SE.

Comment: While a *valid* answer, two things: (1) You really shouldn't be looking a models - what if Apple comes up with an "iPhone SE version 2" with a 4.2 inch screen? At the very least, use *"<=" 320* not *"== 320"* (2) More so, does anyone else find it odd that the accepted answer of hiding a status bar - something that only increases available height - is code that checks for width?