# How to hide status bar only on smaller devices?

Tags: ios, swift

I have gone around and around on this. I just want to hide the status bar on devices smaller than the iPhone 6. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243548/hide-status-bar-only-on-iphone-5-5s-se) answer is great but the code is now deprecated and throws an error.

I followed all the advice on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app) post (which was very helpful), and I have working code, but I have to copy and paste onto every view controller. That seems like a bad idea. It certainly doesn't abide by the DRY method.

Here is my code that works for a single view controller:

```
class Step1SplashVC: UIViewController {

var hideStatusBar: Bool = false

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenSize = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

    print("screen size:", screenSize)

    if screenSize <= 320 {
        print("device is too small. need to hide status bar")
        hideStatusBar = true
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
```

My question is, how do I refactor this so that I'm not copying and pasting to every view controller in my project (I have about 35 view controllers in all)?

I tried creating an extension for UIViewController, but it kept throwing an error.

Here is the bad code:

```
extension UIViewController {

    private struct Holder {
        static var hideStatusBar: Bool = false
    }

    var screensize: Bool {
        get {
            return Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) <= 320
        }

        set {
            Holder.hideStatusBar = true
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Property does not override any property from its superclass

So my efforts at creating an extension are not working.

How can I hide the status bar for smaller devices without having to copy and paste code onto every view controller?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't quite understand from your code though how `hideStatusBar` works if `prefersStatusBarHidden` always returns `true`…?

Comment: @shim It doesn't work. I started coding the computed property and got stuck with the 'override var' part. I didn't finish the computed property code for the 'set' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take that code that you wrote (which works for a single view controller) and put it into a `BaseViewController`, a subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var hideStatusBar: Bool = false

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

        print("screen size:", screenSize)

        if screenSize <= 320 {
            print("device is too small. need to hide status bar")
            hideStatusBar = true
            setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can subclass `BaseViewController` on each of your view controllers in your project (replacing `class XYZViewController: UIViewController`), and implement `super.viewDidLoad()`, for example:

```
class Step1SplashVC: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Whatever you want, specific to each VC
    }
}
```

Comment: So I still have to add the subclass in to each VC, but I won't have to copy all the same code into each VC. Just subclass on each VC and I'm good to go, right?

Comment: Exactly - instead of your VCs subclassing `UIViewController` all you're doing is subclassing your custom `BaseViewController`.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I understand the concept of subclassing now and how to apply it to this particular situation. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions cannot / should not override properties/methods from the classes they extend; [see more on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274660/1032372).

Alternatively you could subclass `UIViewController` and implement `prefersStatusBarHidden` in the subclass, but then you'd have to apply that subclass to all your view controllers.

Note also if your app's flow is centred around `UINavigationController` for example, you may be able to implement your changes in a single subclass of that rather than in each `UIViewController`.

An example using `UIViewController` subclassing (you may want to structure your implementation differently):

```
class MyViewControllerBaseClass: UIViewController {
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return shouldHideStatusBar 
    }

    var shouldHideStatusBar = true
}

// ……… meanwhile in some other file…

class SomeViewController: MyViewControllerBaseClass {
    // this class now inherits the above property and the implementation of prefersStatusBarHidden
}
```

You can put your code for checking the screen size in the base class as well.

Comment: Ah. Subclassing. That's a new area for me. Can you elaborate? Perhaps give some sample code?

Comment: Updated with a simple example

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide status bar in `AppDelegate.swift`. Only three steps are needed:

1) In `Info.plist` add new row.

Key: `View controller-based status bar appearance`

Value: `No`

2) Now in `AppDelegate.swift` add two variables to get width and height , like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //----- These lines should be added
    public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
    public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
    //------ End
}
```

3) Now you have size of device's screen and you have permission to hide status bar. In `AppDelegate.swift` you have function like this (default it is on top and your first function in `AppDelegate.swift`):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

In this function you just one time check screen size and if it was smaller than 320 (smaller than iPhone SE) then you hide status bar like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //----- These lines should be added
        if(self.screenWidth < 320) {
            UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
        }
        //------ End

        return true
    }
```

That's it.

In this way you check screen size and hide/show status bar just one time.

Hope to be useful. Also sorry about my English.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. There are a couple of problems. 1. By setting the plist key `View controller-based status bar appearance` to NO, I'm no longer able to set display for individual view controllers. 2. `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true` is deprecated in iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

var screenHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

```
if screenHeight < 667 {
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true` is deprecated in iOS 9.